# How to track index on Custom Listview Cell when we click on inside Button (QML)

Tags: qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator, qtableview

I am form iOS background so i will give example of UITableView in iOS.

in table view when we create custom Cell for our application then we get the child view by putting "TAG" on each view including buttons . and it becomes easy to get the "INDEX OF ROW" by clicking on any UIButton.

mean suppose we have a custom list which include many labels, images and button. we can track the specific Cell by clicking on label and images but when we click on Button it does not give us index of that cell until we use some technique to handle this and mostly programmers use tagging to track the view inside cell .

Now my Question is "SAME I WANT TO DO WITH BLACKBERRY 10 LISTVIEW" .

In my situation i have a list view and on click it opens the specific View related to that cell. every thing is working fine when i click on cell every where except Button .

How can i track the index of that Cell on clicking the button. because using index i have to pick value from dataModel .

Please let me know if i am able to tell my problem

> Edits:

This is my Code

I define my list view as

```
 ListView {
            translationY: 130
            dataModel: dataModelList
            listItemComponents: [
                ListItemComponent {
                    type: "item"
                    Chekdata {
                    }
                }
            ]
            onTriggered: {
                var showDetail = productDetailPageID.createObject();
                showDetail.myProfileData=dataModel.data(indexPath);
                navigationPane.push(showDetail);
                console.log(dataModel.data(indexPath)["cat_name"]);
            }
        }
```

where Chekdata.qml is like this

```
import bb.cascades 1.0
import org.labsquare 1.0

Container {
        preferredHeight: 600
        preferredWidth: 768
        layout: AbsoluteLayout {

        }
    WebImageView {
        id: img
        url: ListItemData.offer_image
        preferredWidth: 610
        translationY: 70.0
        translationX: 70.0
        preferredHeight: 250
    }
        Label {
            text:ListItemData.member_id
            translationY: 320.0
            translationX: 70.0
        }

        Label {
            text: ListItemData.offer_type
            translationX: 70
            translationY: 350
        }
        Label {
            text: "Category:"
            translationY: 400
            translationX: 70
            textStyle.fontSize: FontSize.XSmall
        }
        Label {
            text: ListItemData.cat_name
            translationY: 400
            translationX: 210
            textStyle.fontSize: FontSize.XSmall
        }
        Label {
            text: "Offer Added Date:"
            translationY: 440
            translationX: 70
            textStyle.fontSize: FontSize.XXSmall
        }
        Label {
            text: ListItemData.date_start
            translationY: 440
            translationX: 250
            textStyle.fontSize: FontSize.XXSmall
        }
        Label {
            text: ListItemData.discount
            translationY: 480
            translationX: 70
        }
        Label {
            text: "coupon Left :"
            translationX: 400
            translationY: 320
            textStyle.fontSize: FontSize.XSmall
        }
        Label {
            text: ListItemData.coupon_code
            translationX: 570
            translationY: 325
            textStyle.fontSize: FontSize.XXSmall
        }
        Label {
            text: "Location:"
            translationX: 400
            translationY: 360
            textStyle.fontSize: FontSize.XSmall
        }
        Label {
            text: ListItemData.location
            translationX: 520
            translationY: 360
            textStyle.fontSize: FontSize.XSmall
        }
        Label {
            text: "offer Expires :"
            translationX: 400
            translationY: 400
            textStyle.fontSize: FontSize.XXSmall
        }
        Label {
            text: ListItemData.date_end
            translationX: 540
            translationY: 400
            textStyle.fontSize: FontSize.XXSmall
        }
        ImageButton {
            defaultImageSource: "asset:///images/BlueNoseBig.png"
            preferredHeight: 60
            preferredWidth: 150
            translationX: 500
            translationY: 470.0
        }
    }
```

There are main Three elements Webimageview, label, and ImageButton.
and you can see on above code the onTrigger function. this function is not call when i click on ImageButton

Comment: Please show some of your code so that we can see how your button is defined

Comment: @koopajah can tell how i can get index inside onTrigger function by clicking ImageButton

Comment: I apply [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14138094/how-to-implement-the-button-click-event-on-listview-in-blackberry-10-cascades-qm?rq=1) but its not working

Comment: @koopajah have you any idea where i am wrong or if you give me any reference for this solution

Comment: On the click event of your `ImageButton` you should trigger a signal of your `CheckData` component. And on your `ListView` you should catch this signal and set the `currentIndex` to `index` I think

Comment: the main confusion is to get currentIndex on button click

Comment: Did you find out the solution?

Comment: Not yet.. but if you ever get the clue please don't forget to help me.